# Nginx/Django SSL Configuration for a specific sub page

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https

I have an nginx/gunicorn/supervisor/posrgresql server with Django. I server two web pages from this server, with each with its own nginx conf file.  I have purchased and downloaded SSL certificates and they are working in some circumstances.

My nginx conf file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name name.org;
    return 301 https://www.name.org;
{

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.name.org;

    ssl_certificate...

}
```

And so on.  What I want to happen is this:

Either

1.) entire site with all pages https

or

2.) one particular sub-page with https, e.g. https://www.name.org/page, no matter how you get there, name.org/page, https://www.name.org/page, www.name.org/page, internal links, etc.  The point is I need to serve THAT page over SSL.

Currently, name.org takes you to my home page https. www.name.org does not.  I can go to any page on my site, and then enter that page name in the address bar, like https://www.name.org/anypage, and it will reload with the green lock.

I've been looking on stackoverflow, nginx documentation, godaddy (where I purchased my certificates) and everywhere else I can think to search for hours and cannot find anything, so any help will be quite welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first `server` block to include the `www` subdomain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name name.org www.name.org;
    return 301 https://www.name.org;
}
```

This will redirect both `http://name.org` and `http://www.name.org` to `https://www.name.org`. After you've done that, you can remove the `listen 80;` from your second `server` block, as the first one covers that name / port combination, and you'll only be dealing with the ssl version from then on.

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you very much.  I now see why people generally do not do this, though, as it certainly slowed my site down.